# font change and auto resize plus padding

Tags: html, css

I have a footer defined as

```
div#footer { 
    width:100%;  
    bottom:0; 
    background:url(../images/bg_footer0.png) repeat-x;
}
```

whose html body is designed as

```css
html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    font-family:arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#666;
    background:url(../images/bg_body.png) repeat-x;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

But when I change `arial` into `serif` in the font family, the footer becomes padded from the bottom, I guess this is common in all font changes. But why and how can I always add the footer truly at the bottom, no matter what changes ?

Comment: you could absolute position the text at bottom: 0 ; or you could adjust line-height;

Comment: `bottom:0` has no effects if `position:static`

Comment: It might be the `line-height`, try to set it to a fixed value and see what happens. Fonts have different x-heights.

Comment: Oh Thanks, I have many comments, don't know which one is better, thak you a lot :=D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
      div#footer { 
          width:100%;  
          bottom:0; 
          background:url(../images/bg_footer0.png) repeat-x;
          position: absolute;
         }
```

actually you can select it with just

```
         #footer{}
```

unless you have other type of elements with the same id of footer , which would be bad

Comment: Thank you Scott, I have only one footer. I realize using the background footer image is a bad approach, I will try to use simply div and add it borders and colors

Comment: no, the background image should be fine,but that absolute position should fix the little margin you had at the bottom, if for some weird reason it doesn't , which it should , use bottom: -2px;